# Sharing variable context between methods in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I'm building an object that handles a timing method to control refreshing a model with data from the server. It's extremely simple. However, I'm new to Ember and having difficulty understanding scoping and context.

For instance, when I create an object as such:

```
App.ModelRefresh = Ember.Object.extend({
  start: function(){
    this.timer = setInterval(this.refresh.bind(this), 2000);
  },
  stop: function(){
    console.log('stop');
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  },
  refresh: function(){
    console.log('refresh');
  }
});
```

And then create it within a router to handle reloading. Again like so:

```
App.PublishablesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Publishable.fetch();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);

    var modelRefresh = App.ModelRefresh.create();
    modelRefresh.start();
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    modelRefresh.stop();
  }
});
```

In the console I see the error.

`Assertion failed: Error while loading route: ReferenceError: modelRefresh is not defined`

I can get it to run the method `.start()` without hassle (obviously). But I'm able to run `.stop()`. This makes sense, but how do share the newly created modelRefresh between the different route methods. In Backbone.js I would add it to initialize and refer to the parent using `this`. In Ember that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
App.PublishablesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Publishable.fetch();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);

    var modelRefresh = App.ModelRefresh.create();
    modelRefresh.start();
    this.set('modelRefresh', modelRefresh ); 
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    var modelRefresh  = this.get('modelRefresh');
    modelRefresh.stop();
  }
});
```

ROUTER ACTIVATE AND DEACTIVATE
Currently, many people are using the undocumented and private enter and exit hooks to run code whenever Ember activates a route handler or deactivates it.

As of Ember 1.0 RC1, there are public hooks: activate and deactivate. Note that the activate hook will run only when a route handler is activated for the first time. If a route handler's context changes, the setupController hook will run again, but not the activate hook.

```
App.PublishablesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Publishable.fetch();
  },
  activate: function() {
    $('#page-title').text("Publish");

    var modelRefresh = App.ModelRefresh.create();
    this.set('modelRefresh', modelRefresh );
    modelRefresh.start();
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    var modelRefresh  = this.get('modelRefresh');
    modelRefresh.stop();
  }
});
```

On init

```
init: function() {
  var modelRefresh = App.ModelRefresh.create();
  this.set('modelRefresh', modelRefresh );
  this._super();
},
```

Comment: That absolutly worked. I noticed that if I move `modelRefresh.start()` into `activate` alone with the `get` I get the same Assertion fail error. Is there something I should know about activate that would cause this to happen?

Comment: n/m activate happens before setupController so it's probably not been created yet. :)

Comment: Ah ok, instantiating `modelRefresh` in `init` seems to have resolved the error. http://jsbin.com/uQInuHO/1

Comment: If you override init you'll want to call super to allow Ember to still do it's usual init items.